# how to restore sql server database without store procedures?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, database-backups

I made a full database backup.  I wanted to restore this database in another distant machine.

However, database restoration failed with:

```
Msg 7202, Level 11, State 2, Server MySERVER\SQLEXPRESS, Procedure _SBOF_FOO1, Line 17
Could not find server 'svr1' in sys.servers. Verify that the correct server name was specified. If necessary, execute the stored procedure sp_addlinkedserver to add the server to sys.servers.
```

Aparently, there is a store procedure that has a reference to a server 'svr1' which cannot find. How to work around this error?

Comment: http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2560/configure-generic-sql-server-linked-server-names/

Comment: When I refactor (or restore) a database and I need to move the "poninter" I'd like to use the synonyms: (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177544(v=sql.105).aspx). With them you can point a linked server using the qulified name SCHEMA.OBJECT. This should be avoid any server related errors (using deferred name resolution). Actually You'll receive runtime errors (and maybe it's better to get your exception) but you can fix them after the restore is completed.